# How can I set a simple delivery date in ZugFerd/konik?

Tags: vba, vb.net, ms-access, zugferd

I try to set a simple deliver date in Zugferd/konik. I got the class example from Access-im-Unternehmen and it runs fine for all examples given there. I call the class from Access VBA, and I'm able to create an pdf/A with xml-invoice as long as I don't add a real date passed in.

The date coming in is `"dd.MM.yyyy"`. And I don't find a way to put it into `\_Lieferdatum`.
Whatever I tried, Error message is:
**System.InvalidCastException: Das Objekt des Typs "java.util.PropertyResourceBundle" kann nicht in Typ "sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle" umgewandelt werden.**

Only this line works:
`_Lieferdatum = New ZfDateMonth(DateUtils.addMonths(New ZfDateDay, 1))`
But thats's not what I need.
What is strange: Visual Studio is set to english, but this message is in german

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports com.neovisionaries.i18n
Imports io.konik
Imports io.konik.zugferd
Imports io.konik.zugferd.entity
Imports io.konik.zugferd.entity.trade
Imports io.konik.zugferd.entity.trade.item
Imports io.konik.zugferd.profile
Imports io.konik.zugferd.unece.codes
Imports io.konik.zugferd.unqualified
Imports java.io
Imports java.math
Imports org.apache.commons.lang3.time
Imports Country = com.neovisionaries.i18n.CountryCode
Imports Currency = com.neovisionaries.i18n.CurrencyCode


Public Class ZuGFeRD_NET

Private _Lieferdatum As ZfDate

Public Property Lieferdatum As String
        Get
            Return _Lieferdatum.toString
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Dim arr = value.Split(".")
            Dim str = arr(1) & "/" & arr(0) & "/" & arr(2)   ' 02/29/2024
            '_Lieferdatum = CDate(value)
            MsgBox("Lieferdatum" & value)  ' 29.02.2024
            _Lieferdatum = New ZfDateMonth(DateUtils.addMonths(New ZfDateDay, 1))
            MsgBox(_Lieferdatum.getFormatCode())  '610

            '_Lieferdatum = New ZfDateDay(DateUtils.parseDate(value))
            '_Lieferdatum = New ZfDateDay(DateUtils.parseDate(value, "yyyyMMdd"))
            '_Lieferdatum = New ZfDateDay(DateUtils.parseDate(value, "dd.MM.yyyy"))

            '_Lieferdatum = New ZfDateDay
            '_Lieferdatum.setDate(FormatNumber(arr(0)))
            '_Lieferdatum.setMonth(FormatNumber(arr(1)))
            '_Lieferdatum.setYear(FormatNumber(arr(2)))

            _Lieferdatum = New ZfDateDay(DateUtils.parseDate(str, "yyyyMMdd"))

        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no `imports` keyword in VBA. This code looks like VB.NET. Tag added

Comment: If the error message is in German and an English error message is expected then the message may be coming from Zugferd